# Receiving error message when testing GLUT in VSCode on Windows 10

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-code, glut, freeglut

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I've been trying to solve this problem for the past week, and have had no success.  I've scoured the Internet to solve the issue, but to no avail.  I'm trying to create a simple GLUT Open GL application in C, using the following code:

```
// This is a very basic Windows C application for testing GLUT (and compatible implementations such as freeglut).
#include <GL/glut.h>

/* Main method */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // Initialize GLUT functionality
  glutInit(&argc, argv);

  // Create a single window
  glutCreateWindow("GLUT Test");

  // Run the GLUT event loop
  glutMainLoop();

  return 0;
}
```

I've followed along with the following tutorial, and everything builds successfully:

https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/using-glut-with-mingw/

Unfortunately I keep receiving the following error message when trying to run the program:

```
freeglut (C:\users\jason\Google Drive\code\c\test\example.exe): fgPlatformInitialize: CreateDC failed, Screen size info may be incorrect
This is quite likely caused by a bad '-display' parameter
```

I have tried so many things to fix this, from trying to directly set the display value in fgPlatformInitialize, to setting a DISPLAY environment variable in Windows itself, and many other solutions.  Nothing is fixing that error message.

For reference I am using Visual Studio Code, FreeGLUT and Windows 10.  Should I just install everything on my Arch Linux box instead? :)

Please help and thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having this issue, finally figured it out and answered my own question.

Tracked down an excellent website called the OpenGL Programming Guide.

It's the Official Guide to Learning OpenGL (albeit version 1.1), but great in that all the examples are in C specifically.

URL: https://www.glprogramming.com/red/index.html

To start with, you need to declare the OpenGL and OpenGL Utility Libraries:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

Then create a display function (can be named anything, but this is convention):

```
{
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear all pixels from buffer

  glColor3f(1, 1, 1); // set the color palette to be white

  glBegin(GL_POLYGON);           // Create a polygonal object (a while box in this case)
  glVertex3f(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.0); // This means the polygon's "corners" as defined by these commands
  glVertex3f(0.75f, 0.25f, 0.0); // This means the polygon's "corners" as defined by these commands
  glVertex3f(0.75f, 0.75f, 0.0); // This means the polygon's "corners" as defined by these commands
  glVertex3f(0.25f, 0.75f, 0.0); // This means the polygon's "corners" as defined by these commands
  glEnd();

  glFlush(); // Start processing buffered OpenGL routines
}
```

Then create an init function to wire up OpenGL view (again can be named anything):

```
void init(void)
{
  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0); // Set background color to black (last param is opacity, but doesn't seem to work)

  // Initialize viewing values
  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);            // Look this guy up
  glLoadIdentity();                       // Still have no idea what this means
  glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0); // Specifies the coordinate system OpenGL assumes as it draws the final image and how the image gets mapped to the screen
}
```

Lastly, just call all the necessary functions in the main c function and voila!

```
// Declare initial window size and display mode (single buffer and RGBA)
// Open window with "hello" in its title bar
// Call initialization routines
// Register callback function to display graphics
// Enter main loop and process events
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  glutInit(&argc, argv); // Initialize the GLUT OpenGL Utility Toolkit framework

  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB); // Display mode which is RGB (Red Green Blue) type, single buffer as we're not switching screen buffers

  glutInitWindowSize(250, 250); // Declares window size in width and height

  glutCreateWindow("Hello"); // Set the name for the window box

  init(); // call the init function defined previously

  glutDisplayFunc(display); // call the glut display function, passing in your display function

  glutMainLoop(); // Enter main loop and process events

  return 0; // ANSI C standard requires main to return int
}
```

I hope that helps anyone else who may have been stuck on this!